# Is the PayPal APP-ID account or app specific?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I just got issued a PayPal APP-ID, but was wondering:

Is this APP-ID tied to the PayPal account I used to apply for it, or can it be used with any of my accounts?

ie. say I apply on apps.paypal.com with my business PayPal, paypal@jessedevelopment.example.com. I get approved.

Now, with the same application, I want to also sell my service as a freelancer, so I add the API credentials for my personal PayPal account jessefreelancer@example.com into my application. Do I have to reapply and get a new APP-ID for use with this new account since it's a new PayPal account, or could I still use the same APP-ID since it's the same application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are tied to the PayPal account. Though ownership can be transferred in some cases, you can't share an existing AppID across multiple PayPal accounts.

Comment: So in other words I have to apply for two APP-ID values if I want to use two paypal accounts even if they're the same app?